# Apache Pulsar on hybrid cloud

Tags: cloud, azure-cloud-services, apache-pulsar, hybrid-cloud, pulsar

I want to use Apache Pulsar on a hybrid cloud where I want to deploy Apache Pulsar cluster on cloud.My subscriber will be on cloud and consumer will be deployed on premises. Is it possible to have this sort of configuration for pulsar? If yes, what configurations need to be done to have subscriber on cloud and consumer on premise?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.   As long as you have access, you will have no issues.

StreamNative Cloud does it with OAuth.

Here are some references

https://github.com/streamnative/examples/tree/master/cloud/go

https://streamnative.io/blog/engineering/2021-11-17-building-edge-applications-with-apache-pulsar/

https://github.com/tspannhw/SpeakerProfile/tree/main/2021/talks